# Producing for loop to compute errors for montecarlo integration with different sample sizes

Tags: python, for-loop, montecarlo

Basically, I'm trying to create a for loop which computes the estimates and errors for  the integral below for different sample sizes.:

[image]

This is the code for a single calculation:

```
import numpy as np
truetheta = 0.2

m = 10000

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, m)

y = (x)**4
naive = (np.sum(y)/m)
error = abs(naive - truetheta)
```

However, I want to produce one error for M = 2^i, with i = 1, 2, ... 10

My attempt looks as follows:

```
N = 10
sample_size = np.zeros(N)

# for loop creates sample size 2, 4, 8, 16 ....1024
for n in range(N):
    sample_size[n] = 2**(n+1)



# store output
naive = []
errornaive = []

# for-loop to compute error for different sample sizes
for i in (int(sample_size)):
    m = 2**i
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, m)
    y = x**4
    naive[i] = (np.sum(y)/m)
    errornaive[i] = abs(naive - truetheta)
```

When i run the code  i get the error:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I'm not really sure how to work around this issue, or whether the remainder of the loop is sound. So i'm asking for a bit of assistance here, could someone offer a solution to my error message? and 2, does anyone have a better suggestion than mine to perform the calculation?

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Error simply stems from you trying to convert an numpy array into 1 integer: `int(sample_size)`.  You'd have to convert each element, but better yet, just make it integers to start with; `sample_size = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)`

Comment: and i now see you are doubly computing the exponent; `m = 2**i == 2**(2**(n+1))`. That very very very big. Use `i` directly, and append the results to `naive`. You can compute `errornaive` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, your first suggestion did indeed solve the first error message, and I see that the double computation would indeed create a big number. I'll try to wrap my head around the append function because my storage seems to be unsound.

I get the error message IndexError: list assignment index out of range-

Comment: Yes `naive` is of length 0, you are trying to assign things into it, and you are trying to use the variable `i`  which is *not* an index here. It's the number of monte carlo steps. You can just append results to the list like normal `naive.append(another_datapoint_here)`.

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir, that did the trick. If you don't mind me asking, since I am new on this site. Should I post an answer to my own question crediting you, or should i just leave it as is?

Comment: Self answers are fine https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

With the help of some very helpful comments I managed to create the following code:

```
N = 20
sample_size = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)

# for loop creates sample size 2, 4, 8, 16 ....1024
for n in range(N):
    sample_size[n] = 2**(n+1)



# store our output
naive = []

# for loop to compute error for different sampel sizes
for i in (sample_size):
    m = i
    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, m)
    y = x**4
    naive.append(np.sum(y)/m)
 
# convert to array and get errors
naivearray = np.array(naive)
naiveerror = abs(naivearray - truetheta)
```

This runs without errors, but it's not pretty.